# How can I change the cipher suite on wpa_supplicant

Tags: networking, configuration, ethernet, wpa, macsec

I started to use wpa_supplicant to configure a MacSec connection with another computer, the problem is that there are several options that I do not find in the template of wpa_supplicant.

https://w1.fi/cgit/hostap/plain/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf

My question is if it is possible to change the cipher suite from GCM-AES-128 (default) to another of the 3 available in the protocol. Also, I would like to know why the parameter "macsec_offload" is not a valid one for my wpa_supplicant, although the version that I have is the same as the one shown in the link.

Thanks!